# Count percentage but I get syntax error

Tags: mysql

Please look into this code for me when i try it I get syntax error.

```
SELECT Category,  
    COUNT(*) AS Total, 
    (COUNT(*) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Item WHERE Department='Popular')) * 100
    AS 'Percentage to all items', 
FROM Item
WHERE Department='Popular'
GROUP BY Category;
```

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: There is no [tag:php] or [tag:json] in the question. Please use only the matching tags to tag a question. Also read [ask].

Comment: I want to output tge results in json

Comment: There's no json in mysql. LOL. You need PHP to encode that for you

Comment: MySQL error messages contain the magic word **"near"**. It tells you where the parser found the problem.

Comment: You need to replace 'Percentage to all items', with "Percentage to all items"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is an extra comma after `'Percentage to all items'**,**` , is it typo or intentionally? this comma should be removed and then try plz :)

so sql should be:

```
SELECT Category, COUNT(*) AS Total , 
    (COUNT(*) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Item WHERE Department='Popular')) * 100 AS 'Percentage to all items'
    FROM Item WHERE Department='Popular' GROUP BY Category;
```

Comment: Also replace the single quote with double quote in "Percentage to all items"

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. But I just have one extra question to complete my statement. I want to rank the results with a number let say the higher percentage gets number 1 second number 2 and so on.

Comment: please try something like this,

`SELECT id, score, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank FROM test p, ( SELECT @curRank := 0 ) q ORDER BY score`